When is Star Wars set?
I am wondering, when we say "a long time ago in a galaxy far, far away'', is there anything in the movies or in the canon, or in the comics that suggests when that is.
4 billion years ago, 300 million, something else?

That would suggest that the light from the Star Wars galaxy would reach Earth roughly 3 million years after the events in Star Wars. Unless the ET species has lived for more than 3 million years after the events of Star Wars, we can assume that the light from that galaxy has yet to reach us.

Per The Star Wars Book

IS STAR WARS SET IN THE PAST?
Yes. It takes place a long time ago, but people travel the Star Wars galaxy in spaceships and have all kinds of technology way more
advanced than ours. Their galactic society started before our own, so
they got a head start.
HOW FAR IN THE PAST IS IT SET?
Well, that's never specified with an exact date. Think of "A long time ago" as the Star Wars version of "Once upon a time." It's there
to lend an air of poetry to the saga and clearly establish that Star
Wars is more fantasy than science fiction.


There isn't a direct correlation between the timeline of the Star Wars universe and our real-life Earth-based calendar systems. By saying that the story is set "A long, long time ago," Lucas was keeping the setting intentionally vague.
When fans discuss events within the Star Wars universe, they typically count in years relative the events of the original 1977 film, with years being denoted as either "BBY" (Before the Battle of Yavin) or "ABY" (After the Battle of Yavin).
This dating system has been used in Star Wars stories, and so can be regarded as canonical. The first on-screen use of the BBY timeline was in the 2022 Disney+ series "Andor", in which a title card reads "5 BBY".
Presumably the years in this context would be the years of the Galactic Standard Calendar, which are calculated relative to the capital planet, Coruscant. The relationship between Galactic Standard years and Earth years has not been established, and may be very different indeed.


A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away

This is about as blatant as a director is able to tell you that there is no connection. The above is a terser way to convey to the viewer that:

This story's setting is so ridiculously unrelated to anything in our real lives that there's no point trying to find any kind of connection.

For nerd points, it is decidedly difficult to define synchronicity (i.e. what happens at the same time, using a shared clock of some kind) for things that are thousands of lightyears removed from one another, due to relativistic effects and the impossibility to share any kind of information at these distances, since information is bound by the speed of light as well.
For reference, if humanity immediately sent out a signal upon learning about relativity, in the hope that someone there would pick up the signal, it would take another 24,900 years to reach that galaxy, i.e. 249 times as long as it has already been travelling up to today. And it would take another 25,000 years for us to receive the reply. Let alone that we could use these signals to somehow agree on the same clock and therefore the order of events in both our galaxy and theirs.
In short, the movie specifically establishes that the setting is uncorrelatable to our reality, and real world physics back this up due to the distances involved. That's both in-universe and out-of-universe confirmation that this question is not meaningfully answerable.
The closest you're going to get to an answer is that it was "a long time ago", and it's up to you to wonder if this is factoring in the lightyear distance that it would take for information to travel from there to here.

Assume it takes place in our universe.
Wookiepedia says the Star Wars galaxy is 13 Billion years old.
It also says a year is 365 days and a day is 24 hours, based on Coruscant
The oldest known galaxy in the universe is 13.4-13.5 billion years old.
Therefore the longest time ago it could be is like 500 million years ago. So somewhere between whatever the shortest amount a human would consider a long time and 500 million years.

A nice bit of sleuthing. This answer would be improved by quoting the source of the assertion that the galaxy is 13Bn years old, rather than just waving a hand at wookieepedia.

Star Wars is more in line with the Fantasy genre, hence homage to classic title opening "Once Upon a time".
"A long time ago" suggests story telling takes place ancient society. The expanded universe star wars have events that take place over span several thousand years, with it's oldest government and Jedi order, being 25,000 years old. WHEN it's set has no place value, since there's no indication when it occured in reference to our time scales.
